# How to deal with Date Format of SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have web application in asp.net 4.0 am using calender control for "FromDate" 
when am going to fetch my records then my query is as follows:

```
Select * 
From Sec_RoleFeatures
Where RoleId = 39 
  and FeatureCode = 'MR' 
  and FromDate='12/12/2012 11:05:05 AM'
```

as this `` `FromDate `` field date format does not match with sql format so result is that it does not give records give `null`.

so in this case what can I do? how to match my date format with sql date format?

Answer (score 5):

Don't pass the value in the SQL at all. Use parameterized SQL for *all* values like this. Benefits:

- The SQL is cleaner (no mixing of code and data)
- Avoids SQL injection attacks (probably not relevant here, but definitely for strings)
- Avoids conversion issues

Fundamentally, avoid string conversions where you can. Not just in database work, but in general. Try to keep your data in its "natural" type (`DateTime` here) for as long as possible. In this case you don't *need* to convert it to a string at all (as you can use parameters) so why do so?

See the documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example of how to use parameters in your SQL.

Comment: +1, Yes, You are absolutely right, I recommended the way `YYYYMMDD` in case the date entry is entered directly, not from a C# application.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reverse ISO format: yyyymmdd (so 12/12/2012 is 20121212) and use 24 hr format for time.

```
Select * From Sec_RoleFeatures Where (RoleId = 39) and (FeatureCode = 'MR') and (FromDate = '20121212 11:05:05')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Casting :

```
Select * From Sec_RoleFeatures Where RoleId = 39 and FeatureCode = 'MR' and 
CAST(FromDate AS DATE) = CAST('12/12/2012 11:05:05 AM' AS DATE)
```

The advantage here is, it will compare only the dates ignoring the time part.

Comment: I don't want to ignore time part.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
Select * From Sec_RoleFeatures Where RoleId = 39 and FeatureCode = 'MR' and  CONVERT(varchar(10),FromDate,101)='12/12/2012'
```

Comment: It's works but not completely it not given Time means '12/12/2012 11:05:05 AM'

Comment: If you *have* to do a conversion, prefer to convert strings to dates rather than dates to strings. And try to avoid ambiguous formats.